# Why is my Perl regex removing the . before the file extension?

Tags: regex, perl

I have this regexp:

```
$f =~ s/[.\W_]//g;
```

which keeps just the numbers, letters and . in the filename (filename.ext).

But it's not keeping the `.` (dot) before the file extension. So if I have:

```
my $f = "prn-the_rush show.jpg"
```

The result is  `prntherushshowjpg`  but the `.` is missing!

I want `prntherushshow.jpg` as result.

How do I do that?

Comment: `.` inside a bracketed character class loses its special meaning and does _not_ need to be escaped.

Comment: `\W` is matching your dots and removes them

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rewrite the character class to explicitly match the complement of what you want to keep:

```
$f =~ s/[^A-Za-z0-9.]//g;
```

You can also accomplish the same thing more efficiently by using `tr///` (a.k.a. `y///`):

```
$f =~ tr/A-Za-z0-9.//cd;
```

Comment: Why not make it easier with `/i` switch?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$f =~ s/[^a-zA-Z0-9\.]//g;
```

Answer (score 2):

Many people have already given you regular expressions that work for your problem. However, when I run across these cases, I often end up separating the filename from the extension so I can play with the filename separately:

```
my( $name, $extension ) = $filename =~ /(.+)\.([^.]+)\z/;
$name =~ s/.../.../;
my $new_filename = join '.', $name, $extension;
```

I've often wanted an `rsplit` for this sort of thing so I can break it into a limited number of elements starting from the right:

```
my( $name, $extension ) = rsplit /\./, $filename, 2;   # fake code
```

When you do it this way, if you decide to remove the `.` from your filename portion, you don't have to play tricks with the regex to protect the final `.` before the extension.

Comment: your `$2` capture that is being assigned to `$extension` includes the initial dot. You are adding a second one with the call to `join`.

Answer (score 1):

***Script:***

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

my $f = "prn-the_rush show.jpg ";
   $f =~ s/[^a-z\d\.]//ig;

print "$f\n";
```

***Output:***

```
prntherushshow.jpg
```